# Unable to create EXTERNAL TABLE to Azure SQL Server on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, azure, external-tables, azure-synapse, azure-sql-database

Unable to create EXTERNAL TABLE at Azure SQL Data Warehouse pointing to Azure SQL Server.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE EX_SOURCE
WITH ( 
    TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = 'SERVER.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = 'DB_NAME',
    CREDENTIAL = "CREDENTIAL"
)
;
```

Responds with:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'RDBMS'
```

Does anyone know  a workaround for this?

I also have tried to to do it the other way around. It allows me to create an EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE pointing to Azure SQL Data Warehouse from Azure SQL Server and to create EXTERNAL TABLE, but when I try to query it I get:

```
Error retrieving data from one or more shards.  The underlying error message received was: 'Parse error at line: 1, column: 36: Incorrect syntax near '='.'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse, today, only supports creating an external data source to Azure Blob Storage and Hadoop ('hdfs://') targets. The current external query syntax for Azure SQL Database does not support Azure SQL Data Warehouse.